# Flex:- draw a pie chart in a popup window

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flex4

I have drawn a pie chart,I want that when I roll over my mouse on this pie chart,
   a popup window opens and the same pie chart is drawn in this popup window.(Only the pie
   chart in this popup window is magnified).Take any input directly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can have a customized pie chart component (higher resolution) in the pop up container and initialize it with the same data.

Comment: how can you give me an example

Answer (score 0):

Make a second application which is just a wrapper for your pie chart. Size it larger. In  your first app (main browser) use `ExternalInterface` class to call Javascript on the page that opens a popup window containing the 2nd app, which you pass the same dataProvider that you used for the first pie chart. Rinse and repeat for subsequent popups. You can even use the same popup window and pass different data.